# ASP.NET Core 5: output folder is missing certain assemblies

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I upgraded my ASP.NET Core project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5 and noticed that certain Microsoft dll's are missing in the build output folder, such as:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll,  
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 
...
```

Unfortunately I have extranal tools (DI, Migration tool...) that's depend on this dll's to be in the output folder.

I know that Microsoft did that intentionally but due to my dependencies I need a workaround.

**Note that:**

```
  <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

is no longer working in .NET 5

**Edit:**

I consumed 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions' as a nuget but it also not working

Comment: Do you have `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` in your PackageReference (nuget)?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the post so it clear @FrankNielsen

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio Installer and **update your visual studio** to the lastest version.
[image]

Then make sure your Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll has the **right version** , open nuget

package can check it.

And you can check the .net 5.0 install page, it needs the **vs 16.9**, I have the similiar error, but solved this

problem by just updating the visual studio.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

Comment: I used the latest VS 2019 (16.9.5) and the latest .Net 5 (5.0.203) when writing this post so this is not the problem, just to make it clear its not a run time error, its the build process that doesn't copy the dll's into the output folder.